# How do I call setState with the previous state plus an additional value in a redux connected controlled component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How do I call setState with the previous state plus an additional value in a controlled component?

The typical example is:

```
Increment() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({counter: prevState.counter = props.step})
}
```

However, how do you update the state based on the prevState and a value from a handler. 
For example (and I know this example is wrong, since you cannot pass value into the setState callback):

```
HandleOnAddItem(evt, { value }) {
    this.setState((prevState, props, value) -> ({items: value, ...prevState.items})
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are passing that value in event handler function, then it will be available inside setState without passing into updater function.

Write it like this:

```
HandleOnAddItem(evt, { value }) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({items: value, ...prevState.items}))
}
```

If you are updating only one state property that doesn't dependent on previous state, as i think in your case, then directly you can write:

```
HandleOnAddItem(evt, { value }) {
    this.setState({ items: value })
}
```

Check this answer for more details: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Example:

```js
//setTimeout will call the method after 2sec, similar to setState
let abc = a => {setTimeout(() => console.log('a', a), 2000)}; 

abc(10);
```

Comment: Why is the spread syntax applied after a new value has been updated, does it matter? Or is it a semantic issue?

Answer (score 1):

Because of javascript [`closures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), inner functions have access to the variables of outer functions, a value passed as parameter on to the handler function is available in the `setState callback`. You can use it like

```
HandleOnAddItem(evt, { value }) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) -> ({items: value, ...prevState.items})
}
```